# Search interface with swipe tabs android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I need some help to implement search ability in different swipe tabs.
I have an `Activity` A which is also the main activity for my search interface (search bar at the top). This activity should pass the search string to respective fragments based on the tabs, All, Organizations, and persons.

I am not able to figure out how can I pass search string to the respective fragments. Does anyone have any suggestions or working code which i can refer to ?

Thanks

Please find the attached snapshot.

[image: swipe]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Activity`, declare a public variable

```
public String search;
```

In the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` of your `Activity`, add

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search)
        .getActionView();    

SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        search = query;
    }
};
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);
```

and in your `Fragment`, you can access the string as

```
String query = ((MyActivity)getActivity()).search;
```

Try this. This will work.

Comment: Ok .. thanks .. let me try this ! Is it possible to do if i am using something like this  if ((Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY); ....... I mean instead of using OnQueryTextListener ?

Comment: that does sound possible ... please do try it and let me know if it works :)